# Calculate Phase Shift Using FFT

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, python, phase, c#

I'm not a specialist in this field and learnt FFT fairly recently.

I want to calculate phase difference of between 1 MHz signals sampled at 4 MHz. The sample counts are both 144. I think the magnitudes and the frequencies are all correct. But phase shifts are off.

So, I decided to go back and start with simpler sets of data. I do fft on 16 samples of a channel sampled at 16 Hz.

The code that actually makes wave data is as below;

```
    class FunctionGenParam
    {
        public int portionNumber;
        public double nXRes;
        public int sampleCount;
        public FunctionGenParam(int portionnumber, double xresolution, int samplecount)
        {
            portionNumber = portionnumber;
            nXRes = xresolution;
            sampleCount = samplecount;
        }
        public List<GraphParam> lstGraphParam = new List<GraphParam>(0);
    }
    private void GenerateYourPortion(object functionparam) //portionNumber를 object로 정의한 것은 parameterizedthreadstart가 object를 받기 때문에 나중에 편하려고..
    {
        FunctionGenParam param = (FunctionGenParam)functionparam;
        List<double> lstdbl = new List<double>(0);
        float start = param.portionNumber * param.sampleCount;
        
        for (float n = 0; n < param.sampleCount; n++)
        {
            float y = 0f;

            if (param.lstGraphParam.Count== 0) return;
            for (int i = 0; i < param.lstGraphParam.Count; i++)
            {
                switch (param.lstGraphParam[i].Graph)
                {
                    case "Sine":
                        float sineresult = (float)Math.Sin((((n+start) * param.nXRes) 
                               + param.lstGraphParam[i].PhaseAngle) * radian 
                               * param.lstGraphParam[i].Frequency) 
                               * param.lstGraphParam[i].Amplitude 
                               + param.lstGraphParam[i].Offset;
                        y += sineresult;
                        break;
                    case "Cosine":
                        float cosineresult =(float)Math.Cos((((n + start) * param.nXRes)
                               + param.lstGraphParam[i].PhaseAngle) * radian 
                               * param.lstGraphParam[i].Frequency) 
                               * param.lstGraphParam[i].Amplitude 
                               + param.lstGraphParam[i].Offset;
                        y += cosineresult;
                        break;
                    //case "Pulse":
                    //    float pulseresult = (float)Math.Sin((((n + start) * param.nXRes) + param.lstGraphParam[i].PhaseAngle) * radian * param.lstGraphParam[i].Frequency) * param.lstGraphParam[i].Amplitude + param.lstGraphParam[i].Offset;
                        
                    //    if (pulseresult > 0f)
                    //        y += param.lstGraphParam[i].Amplitude + param.lstGraphParam[i].Offset;
                    //    else
                    //        y += -param.lstGraphParam[i].Amplitude + param.lstGraphParam[i].Offset;
                    //    break;
                }
            }
            //inputsignal.channel1.lstInData.Add((double)y);
            lstdbl.Add((double)y);
        }
        arDblList[param.portionNumber] = lstdbl;
    }
```

And the code that calls it is as below;

```
#region CH1

        if (lvSig_In_CH1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[Environment.ProcessorCount];

            nXRes = 360 / (double)inputsignal.SamplingFrequency;

            int nSampleCount = (int) (inputsignal.SamplingFrequency * Convert.ToInt32(tboxSeconds.Text.ToString()))/threads.Length;
            if (tboxSampleCount.Text != "")
                nSampleCount = (int)(Convert.ToInt32(tboxSampleCount.Text.ToString())/threads.Length);
                            
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
            {
                FunctionGenParam paramchannel1 = new FunctionGenParam(i, nXRes, nSampleCount);
                for (int j = 0; j < lvSig_In_CH1.CheckedItems.Count; j++)
                {
                    GraphParam gpm = new GraphParam(lvSig_In_CH1.CheckedItems[j].SubItems[1].Text, // Graph Type
                        Convert.ToSingle(lvSig_In_CH1.CheckedItems[j].SubItems[2].Text), // Frequency
                        Convert.ToSingle(lvSig_In_CH1.CheckedItems[j].SubItems[3].Text), // Amplitude
                        Convert.ToSingle(lvSig_In_CH1.CheckedItems[j].SubItems[4].Text), // Phase
                        Convert.ToSingle(lvSig_In_CH1.CheckedItems[j].SubItems[5].Text)); // Offset
                    paramchannel1.lstGraphParam.Add(gpm);
                }
                threads[i] = new Thread(GenerateYourPortion);
                threads[i].Start(paramchannel1);
            }

            // Thread.Join을 통해서 모든 쓰레드가 다른 쓰레드가 작업 중일 때는 기다렸다가
            // 자기 차례가 오면 자기 작업을 수행하도록 한다.
            // 이건 쓰레드를 Start 시키고 난 후에 호출해야한다.
            for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
                threads[i].Join();

            for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
            {
                inputsignal.channel1.lstInData.AddRange(arDblList[i]);
            }
        }
        inputsignal.channel1.ElapsedSeconds = Convert.ToSingle(tboxSeconds.Text);

        #endregion CH1
```

Now assume shift is 1.5 degree.

The results are below;
Frequency: Result

- 1 : 1.5 (Correct)
- 2 : 3.0 (Doubled!!!)
- 3 : 3.0 (Tripled!!!)

Now assume shift is 180.
Frequency: Result

- 1 : 180 (Correct)
- 2 : 360 (Doubled!!!)
- 3 : 180 (Correct)
- 4 : 360 (Doubled!!!)

This is Time Domain of 2 Hz with 180 degree phase difference;
[image]

And this is the table of data;
[image]
As you can see, only when the frequency is 1 Hz, the phase angle is correct.

This is the frequency domain graph with data. The grey graph shows phases;

[image]
I use VS C# code to get the phase angle as below;

```
double nPhaseAngle = 0d;
nPhaseAngle = Math.Atan2(cpxchannel1[i].Imaginary/10, cpxchannel1[i].Real);

nPhaseAngle = nPhaseAngle * (180 / Math.PI) + 90;
if (nPhaseAngle < 0)
   nPhaseAngle = 360 + nPhaseAngle;
dblchannel1_Phase.Add(nPhaseAngle);
```

Please experts!! Help me. Frankly speaking, I learn how to do it long time ago but still can't figure this thing out.

Sukho Suh

Comment: `cpxchannel1[i].Imaginary/10` why do you divide by 10 here ? It would also be helpful to see how the signals are generated in the first place

Comment: Oh, that didn't change anything. So, I removed that. And instead I multiplied it with Frequency, then the results got all better but not exact on some degrees.

I generate the graphs through multithread as below;

case "Sine":
                            float sineresult = (float)Math.Sin((((n+start) * param.nXRes) + param.lstGraphParam[i].PhaseAngle) * radian * param.lstGraphParam[i].Frequency) * param.lstGraphParam[i].Amplitude + param.lstGraphParam[i].Offset;
                            y += sineresult;
                            break;

Comment: Please edit and update our question. Code is very difficult to read in the comment.

Comment: Hilmar! I just updated my question. Could you please look at it again?